# What are these garden tools used for?

Tags: tools

I received a set of garden tools, and I'm not sure what a couple of them are used for.  Could you help me identify these tools?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

The first one's a manual lawn edger, as shown here

http://bestweedeaters.com/whats-the-best-manual-lawn-edger

Not sure what the second one's for, never seen anything like it, sorry. It's quite difficult to see if its got any gaps behind that front bar, pic's a little dark, might be worth posting more pictures showing it from beneath as well as other angles.

Comment: I grew up with a manual edger.  Great tool but they wear out quickly imo.

Comment: @EvilElf - I use what's  called a half moon edger, had the same one for years, just needs sharpening very occasionally...